# Destructuring type constructors in type-level Scala (type inference issue)

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

I'm trying to represent derived dimensions. The basic setup looks like this:

```
trait Dimension

trait BaseDimension extends Dimension
trait Length extends BaseDimension
trait Weight extends BaseDimension

trait HigherDimension[D <: BaseDimension, E <: Nat] extends Dimension
```

Here, `HigherDimension` is derived from some `BaseDimension` giving it an exponent (`HigherDimension[Length, Nat._2]` ("`Length^2`") which is area).

Now, I want to compute type for a product of two dimensions. One of the cases is when two `HigherDimension`s with the same `BaseDimension` are multiplied (f.ex. `Length^1 * Length^2 = Length^3`):

```
/** Type Class computing product: D1 * D2 **/
trait DimensionProd[D1 <: Dimension, D2 <: Dimension] { type Out <: Dimension }
object DimensionProd {
  def apply[D1 <: Dimension, D2 <: Dimension](implicit prod: DimensionProd[D1, D2]): Aux[D1, D2, prod.Out] = prod

  type Aux[A <: Dimension, B <: Dimension, C <: Dimension] = DimensionProd[A, B] { type Out = C }

  // handle the case with shared base dimension (f.ex. Length^2 * Length = Length^3)
  implicit def higherDimSharedBase[D1 <: HigherDimension[Base, D1E], D2 <: HigherDimension[Base, D2E], Base <: BaseDimension, D1E <: Nat, D2E <: Nat]
    (implicit sum: Sum[D1E, D2E]) = new DimensionProd[D1, D2] { type Out = HigherDimension[Base, sum.Out] }
}
```

But this doesn't work (`implicitly[DimensionProd[HigherDimension[Length, Nat._1], HigherDimension[Length, Nat._2]]]` won't compile). I understand this is due to compiler not being able to figure out type of `Base` / `D1E` / `D2E` from  bounds of D1 / D2.

Everything works when typed explicitly:

```
// this compiles
DimensionProd.higherDimSharedBase[HigherDimension[Length, Nat._1], HigherDimension[Length, Nat._2], Length, Nat._1, Nat._2]
```

The question is how to define `higherDimSharedBase` so that everything can be inferred and it covers only the intended case (two `HigherDimension`s with shared `BaseDimension`)?